# How locale is determined in R

Tags: r, locale

In Japanese locale,
I set env: LANGUAGE as 'en_US' to show error message in English.
This works fine for me.

```
> Sys.setenv(LANGUAGE = "en_US")
> Sys.
Error: object 'Sys.' not found
```

But when I change locale: LC_ALL as 'en_US.UTF-8' before changing LANGUAGE,
error message doesn't changed and shows in default locale.

```
> Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "en_US.UTF-8")
[1] "LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8;LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8;LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8;LC_MESSAGES=ja_JP.UTF-8;LC_PAPER=ja_JP.UTF-8;LC_NAME=C;LC_ADDRESS=C;LC_TELEPHONE=C;LC_MEASUREMENT=ja_JP.UTF-8;LC_IDENTIFICATION=C"
> Sys.
 エラー:  オブジェクト 'Sys.' がありません 
> Sys.setenv(LANGUAGE = "en_US")
> Sys.
 エラー:  オブジェクト 'Sys.' がありません
```

I thought this is because LC_ALL has higher priority than LANGUAGE
and have some side effect, but this is wrong.
When I change LC_ALL after LANGUAGE, error message is show in English.

```
> Sys.setenv(LANGUAGE = "en_US")
> Sys.
Error: object 'Sys.' not found
> Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "en_US.UTF-8")
[1] "LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8;LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8;LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8;LC_MESSAGES=ja_JP.UTF-8;LC_PAPER=ja_JP.UTF-8;LC_NAME=C;LC_ADDRESS=C;LC_TELEPHONE=C;LC_MEASUREMENT=ja_JP.UTF-8;LC_IDENTIFICATION=C"
> Sys.
Error: object 'Sys.' not found
```

Why LC_ALL block LANGUAGE to change error message locale?

Why order of changing LC_ALL and LANGUAGE cause different result?

default environment:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/libblas/libblas.so.3.6.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/lapack/liblapack.so.3.6.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=ja_JP.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=ja_JP.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=ja_JP.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=ja_JP.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=ja_JP.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=ja_JP.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=ja_JP.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.4 tools_3.4.4   


> RStudio.Version()$version
[1] ‘1.1.447’
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve. You should however be aware that, as written in the help files:

> Note that setting category "LC_ALL" sets only categories "LC_COLLATE",
>   "LC_CTYPE", "LC_MONETARY" and "LC_TIME"

so `LC_ALL` does not set `LC_MESSAGES`, as appears also from your output above.

And later:

> Note that the LANGUAGE environment variable has precedence over
>   "LC_MESSAGES" in selecting the language for message translation **on
>   most R platforms**.

Find out more: `?Sys.setlocale()`